# Sending email from a form

Tags: java, email, jsp, forms

I have one problem in the below code first:

```
<form action="resultPage.jsp" >
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h4>
        <label>subject</label> <input name="subject" type="text" value="subject" />
    </h4>
    <textarea rows="7" cols="40" name="comment" >comment</textarea>
    </br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then I write the below code:

```
<%
    MailManager mailManager = new MailManager();
    String subject= request.getParameter("subject");
    String comment=request.getParameter("comment");
    if((request.getParameter("subject")!=null) && (request.getParameter("comment")!=null) )
        mailManager.sendMessage("send E-mail addrs","password","smtp.gmail.com","465", new String[]{"receive addrs"}, subject,comment, "text/html");
%>
```

But I can't send or receive any e-mail.

When I write mailManager.sendMessage() without if statement I give  an exception 
**java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Where does this MailManager class come from?  Doesn't look like a standard (standard as in included in Sun/Oracle deliverables) class.

Comment: Do add a subject before submitting?

Comment: i have wrote this class before and import it to jsp page

Comment: if it's you who wrote that class in the first place, why don't you go look inside the class to see where things go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the fact that leaving out the `if` cause a NullPointerException means that one or both of the `comment` or `subject` parameters is missing.

That would suggest that the problem is in the form.

Use your browser's web developer capabilities to find out precisely what request is being sent to your server.  It looks like it would be a GET request, so the parameters should be in the request URL.

Comment: For instance, with Firefox there are tools in Tools>Web Developer ... or you can install the Firebug add-on.  Other browsers have similar functionality.  Read the online documentation, look through the menus and preferences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found solution reason of exception was that object of `request.getParameter(t1)` been not made, so there was a pointer pointing to null object

For preventing this error we can use below code :

```
<%    
    String str=request.getParameter("t1");
    if (str==null )
        str=0+"" ;
    int i=Integer.parseInt(str);
    out.print(i);
%>
```